# Are there geodesic which intersect themself?

Tags: differential-geometry

Lets consider for example $ \mathbb{R^n} $. Are there geodesics $ \gamma: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R^n} $ which intersect themself?

Comment: Full disclosure - I'm absolutely ignorant in differential geometry. Two things I think I can still say:
1. On the sphere, geodesics are great circles which close on themselves, if that counts.
2. If you don't agree to such intersections (where a geodesic closes on itself), and require for transversal intersections, then I don't think that's possible if you look at the geodesic flow (you should have existence and uniqueness I think).
But again - I know pretty much nothing about this so sorry if this is nonsense.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$, geodesics are straight lines, so no

Comment: Ok, and is it possible if I consider a surface in $ \mathbb{R^n} $?

Comment: I don't know any differential geometry, but I thought geodesics were shortest paths.  If this is so, then I don't see how one could intersect itself.  You could throw out the loop between the first time it visited a point and the second time it did, and get a shorter path.

Comment: Geodesics on a cone ***do*** intersect themselves.

Comment: @saulspatz According to Wikipedia:  "In general, geodesics are not the same as "shortest curves" between two points, though the two concepts are closely related. The difference is that geodesics are only locally the shortest distance between points, and are parameterized with "constant speed". Going the "long way round" on a great circle between two points on a sphere is a geodesic but not the shortest path between the points." and so on.

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks.

Comment: Geodesics on a torus (the curved surface in $\mathbb R^3$ that looks like a donut, not the flat torus $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$) criss-cross each other all the time.

Comment: @kimchilover Did you mean to say that the geodesics on a torus intersect themselves?  If not, why is it relevant that they intersect one another?  Sorry if that's a stupid question, but I can't visualize it.  I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329944/at-what-angles-of-the-solution-are-the-geodesics-on-the-cone-self-intersecting) on self-intersecting geodesics on a cone, but I'll need to do some work to follow it.

Comment: Explaining the comment of @IvanNeretin : Take a cone gotten by taking a sector of a circle and gluing the two radii. Remove the singularity at the vertex by omitting that one point. Now the geodesics here are the lines that are straight when the paper is opened up again, but correctly extended beyond the join. You easily see that any way you start a geodesic, it will intersect itself.

Comment: If you draw a diagonal geodesic on the usual square picture of Klein, it comes back to intersect itself transversally

Comment: @saulspatz Geodescs on the torus are more interesting and more complicated than I remembered.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703549/geodesics-on-torus and the documents cited in the answers.

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks again.  It will take me some time to absorb this, I'm sure.